# ASP.NET role authorization inheritance with ad groups

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, authorization

I'm using the role manager with active directory in a asp.net site to implement security. I have the following :

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="domain\GroupC" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Users are in group A and B and the groups A and B are in group C. The web.config example above does not allow access to the users, if I add the group a and b directly it does.

My question is, is this kind of authorization inheritance supported out of the box with active directory?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129008/does-authorization-in-web-config-check-sub-groups-as-well).

Comment: @king.code thanks, the problem must be that I did logged on/off before testing.